# How to make DataGrid immediately save changes in a cell after editing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there something simpler than this ( [How to make GridControl immediately save changes in a cell after editing](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4155) ) to allow an update to `DataGrid` upon selection being made without having to click somewhere else?

The code to update the data is not issue, but how leave the cell after selection programmatically.

Using `SelectionChanged` event fires before a selection is made.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             //Code here
        }
```

I am currently using `CellEditEnding`

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
        { 
            // code
        }
```

XAML for data binding,

```
    <DataGrid Name="MainTable" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" 
        Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="4" AlternationCount="2" CanUserAddRows="True"
        GridLinesVisibility="None" 
        CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" >
                   <DataGrid.Columns>                          
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Info" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Words">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Path=Info_Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox FontWeight="Light" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" Text="{Binding Path=Info_Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding InfoCollection, Source={StaticResource InfoDataComboBox}}">
                                        </ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                   </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `DataGridComboBoxColumn`? Are you using `DataBinding`? Please add some more information, so we can help you better. If possible, some simple code to we reproduce the problem.

Comment: @schmaedeck, I added the XAML, for just the column with the combo box, but other than that, there is not much else to post.